# Haskell using zip ranges and concatenation

Tags: haskell, concatenation

Trying to solve a problem that requires using a zip, ranges & concatenation to create a list of hexadecimal mappings like [(0,0),(1,1),(2,2),(3,3),(4,4),(5,5),(6,6),(7,7),(8,8),(9,9),(10,'A'),(11,'B'),(12,'C'),(13,'D'),(14,'E'),(15,'F')]

I have been trying things like `zip [0..9] [0..9] ++ zip [10..15] ['A'..'F']`

or `zip [[0..9] [0..9] ++ [10..15] ['A'..'F']]`

I understand the Zip of those group lists would put together the mapped list I need but I just cant seem to get them together and the ++ Sign is the only method of concatentaion we have been introduced too. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

make sure your types match

```
zip [0..9] ['0'..'9'] ++ zip [10..15] ['A'..'F']
```

To see why this is, let's play in ghci:

```
Prelude> :t zip [0..9] [0..9]
zip [0..9] [0..9] :: (Num b, Num a, Enum b, Enum a) => [(a, b)]

Prelude> :t zip [10..15] ['A'..'F']
zip [10..15] ['A'..'F'] :: (Num a, Enum a) => [(a, Char)]
```

as you can see in your second part you zipped some numbers with characters but the first
zipped numbers and numbers. Now GHC does not know how to make a `Char` from number-literals
like `0` and `9` and even tries to tell you this:

```
Prelude> zip [0..9] [0..9] ++ zip [10..15] ['A'..'F']

<interactive>:9:13:
    Could not deduce (Num Char) arising from the literal ‘0’
    ...
```

This is why you need to do the first part like this too:

```
Prelude> :t zip [0..9] ['0'..'9']
zip [0..9] ['0'..'9'] :: (Num a, Enum a) => [(a, Char)]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been so frustrated working with this for the last few hours :) I guess i didn't realize I could do ['0'..'9'] or that there was a difference for that matter, again thanks!

Comment: No problem: small hint: if you post/read the errors carefully you would have had the answer much earlier ;)